# Max File Upload size in PHP 5.3 and IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7

I have installed the PHP 5.3 and configured with IIS 7. I am building the web application to upload the multiple zip files using php. I have change the following value in php.ini of php folder:

```
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
max_file_uploads = 1024
```

I have also check the phpinfo() to check the change effect and it's taking the change. The Problem is that when I upload the smaller size zip file, the file is uploaded but the larger size zip file is not uploaded. What may be the problem. Is there any thing to be change to upload the larger size zip file or need to configure in IIS 7.

Comment: what size of zip file you uploaded

Comment: upto 8 mb can be uploaded and larger than that is not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

try this:
In php  5.3.10

```
upload_max_filesize = 25M
```

or may be in 5.3

```
max_file_uploads = 1024M
```

Comment: I think max_file_uploads is for number of files to be uploaded at once request

Comment: i not found any max_file_uploads in php ini 5.3.10